# Парсинг и (возможно) кодировка - 'Ночь c' in 'Ночь c 27 ноября на 28 ноября' -> False

Tags: python

Имеется такой код, которым парсю сайты:

```
def prepare_content(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree = fromstring(response.text)
    tree.make_links_absolute(response.url)
    return tree
```

Вот пример кода, в котором возникают проблемы:

```
date = day.xpath('.//div[@class="h3"]/text()')[1].strip().split(',')[0]
print('date:', date) # date: Ночь c 27 ноября на 28 ноября
print("'Ночь с' in date:", 'Ночь с' in date) # 'Ночь с' in date: False
if 'Ночь с' in date:
    date = ' '.join(a.split()[-2:])
print('date:', date) # date: Ночь c 27 ноября на 28 ноября
```

Строка `print("'Ночь с' in date:", 'Ночь с' in date)` должна выдавать `True`, а не `False`

Я в кодировках мало что понимаю, но может разница между кодировкой запарсеной информации и кодировкой используемой IDE? Если это так, как привести запарсенные данные к кодировке IDE?

Comment: В date буква c английская. :)

Comment: Вроде в 3-ем питоне не должно быть таких проблем. Попробуйте разве что `type(date)` вывести. Или и впрямь с `c` проблема.

Comment: @andreymal, 'С' таки не кириллица. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить первой строкой в файле с исходным кодом. Подробнее [тут](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
```

Comment: Постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.